# Pythonic way to get initial diff between two lists

Tags: python

I am currently working on a project with Python3, and was needed to implement such code, where I use an API that passes items with limit count, and need to figure out the latest items that have been added.

I'm sure there must be a more pythonic way, but couldn't think of any. Kindly let me know if there's similar duplicate question cause I could not find one.

```
list1 = ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"] # items requested before
list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] # items requested now

for index, item in enumerate(list2):
    if item is list1[0]:
        print(list2[:index])
        break
```

UPDATE:

I have thousands of items in those lists, and majority of list2 duplicates with items in list1. I need somewhat more efficient way to process those diffs.

Comment: well you never really stated what your desire output is...

Comment: `l2_minus_l1 = [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]`

Comment: @clay Love your solution! But could there be any more efficient way? Cause I got like thousands of items in a list... and the vast majority in list2 all duplicates with the list1

Comment: You probably don't want to be using lists in the first place. Can you describe in more detail how `list1` and `list2` get generated?

Comment: I'd presume NunodeSousa's solution is more efficient for large lists. There are probably specialized libraries even more efficient than that, but I don't know off hand.

Comment: @chepner I request it from a 3rd party API, and I get json for response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `list2.index()` to find the index of the first item of `list1` in `list2`:

```
list1 = ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"] # items requested before
list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] # items requested now

print(list2[:list2.index(list1[0])])
```

---

The following part of the code

```
list2.index(list1[0])
```

will efficiently find the first index in `list2` of the first element in `list1`. This is just as efficient as your manually-implemented python loop from an algorithmic point of view, but more efficient in practice since the loop is implemented natively instead of in python. Then, you can use it to take a slice out of your `list2` just like you were already doing in your own solution.

Comment: Thanks! I guess your solution is the most efficient way possible.

Comment: @viz If you're constrained to using lists and can't use any additional ''domain knowledge'', this is the best I can think of right now. If you are able to add more prior knowledge though (for example if you know for sure that items in the list are sorted in some way, like they are alphabetically sorted in your example), then a different solution (like binary search) could be better to find the index faster.

Comment: You can't use [NunodeSousa's simple set operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49391047/908494) without breaking ordering, but you can still get almost all of the efficiency of that answer without the problem. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49391341/908494).

Comment: @Dennis Soemers Well, I actually have a dictionary with the key as "timestamp" and value as unix timestamp(and there's other data as well) for each item in those lists, and the dictionary items are sorted based on the unix timestamp.

Comment: This is still efficient for this usecase because the goal is to stop at the first match, so we can linear search until that match and then just linear copy from there on, if I understand the problem. If so, it's one of the few cases where using `index` actually makes sense.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks a lot for pointing out. I'll look into your answer too!

Comment: Yes exactly, because we only have to find a single match and can just straight up copy everything after that, I suspect this solution will be faster than anything with `set`. Could take some time later to properly time it and figure out for sure though. However, if the lists are really large, and they are indeed known to be sorted according to timestamps, binary search to find the first index may be more efficient.

Comment: @DennisSoemers You're definitely right  I'll try to use other search if the count of initial diff gets larger than expected. It's tiny for now though.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more specific in the first place. Thanks guys anyways!

Comment: @DennisSoemers Yeah, since we're really only using `list1[0]`, obviously any solution that converts all of `list1` to a set is going to be less efficient. NunodeSousa's version does N+M extra work, my version does N extra work, this version does 1 extra work, which is hard to beat. And if you really can `bisect` to turn the other half of the algorithm from N to log N, that's going to be optimal. Except that you still have to iterate worst-case all of list2 to either copy it or shift the elements, so ultimately it's all still linear…

Answer (score 3):

To do a set difference (or intersection, or any other set operation), you don't need to convert *both* lists to sets, just one of them. The set operation actually works by iterating over the second argument and doing a set operation against the `self` argument. (This only works with the named methods, not the operators.)

Similarly, you can write every set operation as a comprehension with only a small constant slowdown, leaving the main iterable alone, and only converting the one you're `in`-testing to a set.

Normally, what you do with this information is convert the smaller one to a set, and leave the other one as a list. But in your case, you want to preserve the order of one of the two. So, leave *that* one as a list, and convert the other to a set:

```
set1 = set(list1)
newlist = [elem for elem in list2 if elem not in set1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem:

```
list(set(list2) - set(list1))
```